# Pick your brain on wp-config.php if statement for multisite

Tags: multisite, wp-config, wp-debug

I am trying to write a if statement into the wp-config.php to only enable define('WP_DEBUG', true); if it's not the main site in a WordPress Multisite install. I just don't know how much of the WordPress codex functions I can call from the config file.

Was thinking

```
if ( is_main_site($blog_id) ) {
  define('WP_DEBUG', false);
}
else {
 define('WP_DEBUG', true);
}
```

But I figured I would pick the communities brain on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to match $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] variable against desired host. Unfortunately wordpress init WP_DEBUG constant before multisite functions are loaded.